# Custom DNS answers

Tags: c, proxy, dns, network-programming

I'm currently working on a project for my summer internship and I've got to make an oblivious DNS translation server. I'm not here to speak about the oblivious part in detail but I'll explane the architecture of my program.

There is a server side that receives obfuscated requests and sends back an answer that it doesn't understand itself.

On the client side there is a proxy that translate requests into obfuscated requests. For that I use an iptables rule to send all DNS requests to a NFQUEUE, and then I work with libnetfilter_queue to handle the packet. 
After that I received the answer from the server I make a DNS answer with all the information I get (from the DNS request and from the server) and send it using libnet.

Now let's talk about my problem : When using my proxy I check the traffic with Wireshark and it seems that my proxy sends valid answers but if I try to browse the Internet with Firefox it doesn't work.
You can find my code here : https://github.com/AurelienCasimir/PrivateDNS

Is there a problem in my way of building DNS packets ?

Here is the DNS sender :

```
int send_answer(char *dst_ip_array, char *src_ip_array, int dport, int sport, int dns_id, char *query, char *req_ip, int logfd)
{
char c;
u_long src_ip = arrayToLong(src_ip_array), dst_ip = arrayToLong(dst_ip_array), requested_ip_long=dotToLong(req_ip);
char requested_ip[4];
u_short type = LIBNET_UDP_DNSV4_H;
libnet_t *l;

libnet_ptag_t ip;
libnet_ptag_t ptag4; /* TCP or UDP ptag */
libnet_ptag_t dns;

char errbuf[LIBNET_ERRBUF_SIZE];
char payload[1024];
u_short payload_s;
char log_buffer[500];
int length = 0;

/*
 *  Initialize the library.  Root priviledges are required.
 */
l = libnet_init(
        LIBNET_RAW4,                            /* injection type */
        NULL,                                   /* network interface */
        errbuf);                                /* error buffer */

if (!l)
{
    length += sprintf(log_buffer + length, "\tlibnet_init: %s", errbuf);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* 
 * build dns payload 
 */
requested_ip[0]=requested_ip_long/(256*256*256);
requested_ip_long=requested_ip_long%(256*256*256);
requested_ip[1]=requested_ip_long/(256*256);
requested_ip_long=requested_ip_long%(256*256);
requested_ip[2]=requested_ip_long/256;
requested_ip_long=requested_ip_long%256;
requested_ip[3]=requested_ip_long;

payload_s = snprintf(payload, sizeof payload, "%c%s%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", 
         (char)(strlen(query)&0xff), query, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x04, requested_ip[0], requested_ip[1], requested_ip[2], requested_ip[3]);

/* 
 * build packet
 */
dns = libnet_build_dnsv4(
type,          /* TCP or UDP */
dns_id,        /* id */
0x8100,        /* request */
1,             /* num_q */
1,             /* num_anws_rr */
0,             /* num_auth_rr */
0,             /* num_addi_rr */
payload,
payload_s,
l,
0
);

if (dns == -1)
{
    length += sprintf(log_buffer + length, "\tCan't build  DNS packet: %s\n", libnet_geterror(l));
    goto bad;
}

ptag4 = libnet_build_udp(
    sport,                                /* source port */
    dport,                                    /* destination port */
    LIBNET_UDP_H + LIBNET_UDP_DNSV4_H + payload_s, /* packet length */
    0,                                      /* checksum */
    NULL,                                   /* payload */
    0,                                      /* payload size */
    l,                                      /* libnet handle */
    0);                                     /* libnet id */

if (ptag4 == -1)
{
    length += sprintf(log_buffer + length, "\tCan't build UDP header: %s\n", libnet_geterror(l));
    goto bad;
}


ip = libnet_build_ipv4(
    LIBNET_IPV4_H + LIBNET_UDP_H + type + payload_s,/* length */
    0,                                          /* TOS */
    242,                                        /* IP ID */
    0,                                          /* IP Frag */
    64,                                         /* TTL */
    IPPROTO_UDP,                                /* protocol */
    0,                                          /* checksum */
    src_ip,                                     /* source IP */
    dst_ip,                                     /* destination IP */
    NULL,                                       /* payload */
    0,                                          /* payload size */
    l,                                          /* libnet handle */
    0);                                         /* libnet id */

if (ip == -1)
{
    length += sprintf(log_buffer + length, "\tCan't build IP header: %s\n", libnet_geterror(l));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


/*
 * write to the wire
 */
c = libnet_write(l);
if (c == -1)
{
    length += sprintf(log_buffer + length, "\tWrite error: %s\n", libnet_geterror(l));
    goto bad;
}
else
{
    length += sprintf(log_buffer + length, "\tWrote %d byte DNS packet; check the wire.\n", c);
}
length = strlen(log_buffer);
write(logfd, log_buffer, length); // Write to the log.
libnet_destroy(l);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
bad:
length = strlen(log_buffer);
write(logfd, log_buffer, length); // Write to the log.
libnet_destroy(l);
return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Here is an example of DNS answer sent by my proxy:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AYto.jpg

Comment: What happens when you use Firefox? Does it send the UDP request to your proxy or it sends it to another DNS server directly?

Comment: It sends it to a dns server, I catch it in the nfqueue and drop it after getting the information needed.

Comment: Can you show the DNS response as it would arrive to the browser?

Comment: I don't have my computer with me at the moment, but I'll edit my question with some dns responses tomorrow.

Comment: I added a screenshot of a DNS answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the DNS response is correct. I would look at:

1. If the flag recursion available is necessary (0x8180)
2. Check the returned IP address is OK. I could not access that IP address that you showed in your image (https://db-ip.com/26.193.206.130)
3. Is the UDP checksum correct?
4. Does the transaction ID correspond to the transaction ID of the DNS query?
5. I'm sure this is OK but just check the server is requesting that Type and Class of address

Comment: 1. Tried with it and it still does'nt work. 2. All the IP addresses in my DB are taken from answers of real DNS servers. 3. In libnet_build_udp is used 0 for the checksum which should let the kernel compute the checksum itself. 4. It is one of the information I take from the packets in the NFQUEU. 5. It could be the tricky part because for the moment my project doesn't handle CNAME entries. (next part of the comment after)

Comment: I don't think it should be a problem, because the request doesn't know if it is a CNAME or a host address, so instead of answering with a CNAME + a host name it just answer with a host name (the other difference is that it answers with only 1 IP address instead of multiple ones)

Comment: @Kromoz0hm, I don't think it is related to CNAME either, this is internal to DNS server. Can you try using that IP address directly in the browser? Add domain name and IP address in hosts file and you that domain name in Firefox (without your solution). That's the way to clarify any possible doubt. In point 4, you can clarify that by capturing both query and response

Comment: Oh you spotted a really stupid error here... I forgot to write the address in network order, so it should be 130.206.193.26. But even after changing this it still doesn't work. I already checked, and it was ok. But I tested it again and it's still ok.

Comment: @Kromoz0hm network order is a typical error, check you're not having the same error in other fields: time-to-live 59 minutes sounds weird. You could have same problem in transaction id. Did you check the new address corresponds to that domain? BTW, if this response is useful you can mark it as useful

Comment: Yeah I used network order in most fields but forgot in this one. I've set TTL to an arbitrary value so that my server won't have to handle too many requests, but I could try with a lower value to see if it changes anything even if it is not very likely. Yes 130.206.193.26 is a correct address for google. Dit it !

Comment: @Kromoz0hm, Is the destination port OK? Did you check you implementation works with nslookup or  a simple C program using getaddrinfo or gethosbyname (old)?

Comment: The destination port is the same as the source port of the request. It doesn't work either. But trying nslookup i've seen something strange that I think I've not seen before : There are ICMP port unreachable messages. I don't understand why...

Comment: @Kromoz0hm, maybe the iptables rule is not handling it well?

Comment: There is only one rule, and it shouldn't interfere with the answers as 53 is their source port  : sudo iptables -D OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0

Comment: It seems that the ICMP messages are not the problem, because I'm not getting them anymore and it's still not working...

Comment: @Kromoz0hm, you will need to invest in debugging what seems obvious and go step by step and look at points where things "should" work. I would first run nslookup and be sure it works. If not,  by some means try to see the DNS message that is received by your proxy at the proxy entry point (and not some middle entry point) and then sniff the DNS response. Go field by field. If you want to include that info in your question, I can help you.